# amplification factor for the Crank Nicolson scheme for the advection equation

Tags: hyperbolic-pde

I will try one more time being more detailed and careful. Consider the transport equation of the form $$u_t+au_x=0, t\in[0,T],x\in \mathbb{R}, a>0$$ and initial condition $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$. I would like to establish stability of Crank-Nicolson scheme for that equation by computing the amplification factor. Consider the following iteration of CN:
$$\frac{u^{n+1}_j-u^{n}_j}{k}+\frac{1}{2}a\frac{u^{n+1}_{j+1}-u^{n+1}_{j-1}}{2h}+\frac{1}{2}a\frac{u^{n}_{j+1}-u^{n}_{j-1}}{2h}=0$$ then I substitute the form $u^n_j=Q^ne^{ijhw}$ in the above equation:
$$\frac{(Q-1)e^{ijhw}Q^n}{k}+\frac{1}{2}ae^{ijhw}Q^{n+1}\frac{e^{ihw}-e^{-ihw}}{2h}+\frac{1}{2}ae^{ijhw}Q^{n}\frac{e^{ihw}-e^{-ihw}}{2h}=0$$ 
from where with we get:
$$Q=\frac{1-i\frac{ak}{2h}\sin(hw)}{1+i\frac{ak}{2h}\sin(hw)}$$
this is a complex number of the form $\frac{1-iC}{1+iC}$, thus I can calculate the absolute value as follows:
$$|Q|=|\frac{(1-iC)(1-iC)}{(1+iC)(1-iC)}|=|\frac{1-C^2-2iC}{1+C^2}|=\frac{(1-C^2)^2+4C^2}{1+C^2}=\frac{(1+C^2)^2}{(1+C^2)^2}=1$$

from where I deduce that for Crank Nicolson method the amplification factor for that equation has the magnitude of:
$$|Q|=1$$
If there is a mistake in the computations please let me know and I proceed from there. But if this is the amplification factor indeed I would like to know if I can deduce stability/conditional stability/instability from it? Is there a possibility of oscillations of any form? It does satisfy the condition less or equal than one, therefore I can use it and will not have problems?

Comment: In the line of equations beginning with $|Q|$, you have made a mistake.  The expression after the third '=' is not correct.  The numerator is the square of what it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the amplification factor is $\le 1$, then your scheme is stable; in your case it is exactly one, so, for this PDE, you won't have unbounded growth of errors. The [Lax theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_equivalence_theorem) then guarantees convergence of the method. In this narrow sense, the Crank-Nicholson method will work for you. (Have a look at [Leveque's book](http://amzn.com/0898716292) if you want a good reference.)

But, your question of whether or not you will have problems is a deeper one and depends on your objectives. While the Crank Nicholson method does not introduce *amplitude* errors, it will incur *phase* errors. By this, it's meant that different Fourier modes will have different group velocities -- this contrasts with the true PDE, where all modes travel with velocity $a$. Depending on what your application is, the dispersion associated with CN is unacceptable, convergent or not, and you'd choose a different approach.

Generally speaking, even for methods that do converge, there is a trade-off between numerical diffusion and numerical dispersion. In some problems, using staggered grids is a great way to wriggle out of this bargain. If you want to know more, I recommend Dale Durran's [Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics](http://amzn.com/1441964118); he has a great treatment of this subject.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Related to the original question: If instead of central differences I would use one sided for $u_x$, I think the amplification factor is again $1$, but I introduce some diffusion and decrease order of accuracy in space to one from two. Would that provide me with unconditionally stable fdm scheme of $O(k^2+h)$ for that equation?